# InfluxDB reusing old value?

Tags: statsd, influxdb, grafana

I have been switching from statsd + graphite + grafana to using influxdb instead of graphite. However somehow InfluxDB behaves a bit differently than graphite used to when it comes to missing values.

If a timeseries does not produce new points for a period of time, the plot in Grafana will continue to show the last value written:

[image]

This happens even when specifying `fill(0)` or `fill(null)` in the query. When using the Data Interface of InfluxDB it also seems to be filling using the previous values:

[image]

Since I have some alerting that will be triggered by missing values, having the old values reused disables my alerts.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a work around? I'm also experiencing the same.

Comment: So far not too much, it appears to be a result from not having fixed timeslots like graphite used to have (where no value = null), so that InfluxDB assumes the same value to be true until a new one comes in. I was hoping that by grouping into 1 minute batches and averaging this would be fixed (no value in group => null average), however this seems not to be the case. Still looking for answers on how to fix this :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show continuous graph, then there is a hack.

Apply `mean()` and `group by()`

For example, something like this:

```
Select mean("fieldName") from measurement where time > now() -1h group by time(10s) fill(0)
```